# java sort list of strings by string value entered by a user

Tags: java, list, sorting

I am looking for a way in java to sort a list of strings based on user input in Java. for example, my list contains `["Pat Henderson", "Zach Harrington", "Pat Douglas", "Karen Walsh"]`, if a user enters the first name `"Pat"` how would I be able to print out only the Pats in the list and same for surnames?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code.

Comment: Iterate through list and when its match print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < str.size() ; i++) {
    if(str.get(i).contains("your_user_input")) {
        System.out.println(str.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer works quicker than mine, but a little bit less readable on a bigger scale.

Answer (score 2):

`.filter()` introduced in Java 8 would to the thing.

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.addAll(Arrays.asList("Pat Henderson", "Zach Harrington", "Pat Douglas", "Karen Walsh"));

String startsWith = "Pat";

List<String> filteredNames = names.stream()
        .filter(name -> name.startsWith(startsWith))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

A little remark. Sorting is when you rearrange the position of the elements without removing any.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am asked as a requirement to sort by first name or by last name so I assumed what the requirement was asking was to show only the names that match the string entered by the user.

Comment: string can be a first name or last name.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that each element of the list have a name and a last name separated by a whitespace or more, with Java 8 you could filter on the name or the last name in this way :

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Pat Henderson", "Zach Harrington", "Pat Douglas", "Karen Walsh");
String nameOrLastNameToFilter = ...;
list.stream().filter(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s+"))
                                .anyMatch(n->n.equals(nameOrLastNameToFilter))
                    )
    .collect(toList());
```