# Java sort by desired String

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am new to the idea of comparators and I am looking into ways to sort strings. In my code, below, I have made a list and sorted through it using the `Collections.sort()` method. Here is the code:

```
public class ComparatorTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList("Bob Stone", "Jordan Brand", "Bob Mass", "Dylan Walsh","Tom Mavis","Bob Ganley"));
        System.out.println("Before sort "+ list);
        Collections.sort(list);
        System.out.println("After sort "+ list);
    }



}
```

How can I modify this to sort using a given String to sort by, instead of just sorting alphabetically?  For example, if I give the string `BOB`then all the BOB's will move to the front of the list. I did ask a sorting question before but I misunderstood the idea of sorting and it was more of a filtering question ([java sort list of strings by string value entered by a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57998146/java-sort-list-of-strings-by-string-value-entered-by-a-user/57998260#57998260)). This question is different from my earlier question because now I am trying to actually sort and rearrange the Strings instead of filtering them.

Comment: What happens to the elements that don't match the criteria?

Comment: You could make your own Comparator implementation that sorts the way you want and call the Collections.sort method that takes a Comparator as a second argument.

Comment: Are you asking about sorting by a special collation that has certain unusual rules about uppercase/lowercase? Your Question is quite unclear as written now. Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: @munk I am planning on having those placed behind the last element of BOB

Comment: Are you asking about case-sensitivity or not?

Comment: I would include case sensitivity yes

Comment: I understand that you want the other names to come after, but what about their ordering themselves? Should they stay in their original order relative to each other, should they be sorted alphabetically, or does it not matter and they can be in any order so long as bob is in the front?

Comment: @munk the elements after Bob should ideally be sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is understand the rules, for example, what happens when:

- Both the left hand side and right hand side start with "Bob"?
- What happens when neither the left hand side and right hand side start with "Bob"?
- Do you care about matching the case?
- Do you only care about first names or should you included the surname or do you want that to be configurable?

A simple implementation might look something like...

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    private String name;

    public NameComparator(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        if (lhs.startsWith(name) && rhs.startsWith(name)) {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        } else if (lhs.startsWith(name)) {
            return -1;
        } else if (lhs.startsWith(name)) {
            return 1;
        }

        return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
    }
}
```

Now, this does a case match (so `bob` is not the same as `Bob`) and will sub-sort all the "Bobs" within their own group

As you see, five seconds of thinking has brought up a lot of possible ways to sort the list, so you need to be aware of your options, which ones you might want to be customisable and which ones you want to be fixed.

You can call this example using something like...

```
Collections.sort(list, new NameComparator("Bob"));
```

Which will, based on your available input, output...

```
Before sort [Bob Stone, Jordan Brand, Bob Mass, Dylan Walsh, Tom Mavis, Bob Ganley]
After sort [Bob Ganley, Bob Mass, Bob Stone, Dylan Walsh, Jordan Brand, Tom Mavis]
```

Comment: All of your `if/else` would be much more easily written using `Boolean.compare`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is much simpler to follow than the tutorials ive been trying to use online for Comparators

Comment: @AndyTurner Undoubtedly, but give then level of the OPs experience, I went for readability and understandability first ;) - I'm sure there are more ways to skin this cat

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you explain the compare method so I can be sure that I fully understand how it's working, please

Comment: Essentially, `Collections.sort` is calling the `compare` method with two items, which it needs to know how they relate to each other, so it can perform it's overall operation - this is essentially a delegation pattern, the work is been delegated.  Based on the requirements of the `Collections.sort` API, you are return either a positive or negative value to indicate how you want the values to be treated (or how they compare to each other based on your custom need).

Comment: @PaPaB1nG0  The compare method it self is pretty simple.  If both elements start with the desired value, then they are compared with each other (essentially doing a sub sort).  If one or the other elements starts with the desired value, then you give them a higher priority.  Otherwise you do a normal compare (as based on the `String`s implementation)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Boolean.compare` method to check if the strings begin with "Bob":

```
Comparator<String> bobsFirst = (a, b) -> Boolean.compare(b.startsWith("Bob"), a.startsWith("Bob"));
```

Comparing them this way around (b first, then a) puts things starting with "Bob" first.

Then, tie break using natural ordering:

```
Comparator<String> comparator = bobsFirst.thenComparing(a -> a);
```

---

Note that `startsWith` is case sensitive. To ignore the case of  "Bob", you could replace `b.startsWith("Bob")` (similarly for `a`) with:

```
 b.regionMatches(true, 0, "Bob", 0, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

## `Collator` class

The rules used in comparing and sorting natural language (human language) are formally referred to as [*collation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation).

In Java, the rules of any collation are defined in a class implementing [`Collator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/Collator.html) class. Usually, its subclass `RulesBasedCollator` is used for comparing/sorting. The [`CollatorProvider`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/spi/CollatorProvider.html) class is an [SPI (service provider interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface) for providing a registered `Collator` implementation. Recent versions of Java default to collation definitions provided by the [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium) in their [*Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository).

Presumably, you are free to build your own `Collator` implementation with such special rules as you desire.

Be aware that collation is a very complicated field, with rules widely varying by human language and by cultural norms. If you are only concerned with American English, you may have few issues. But if you deal with other languages, cultures, or alternate characters such as `©` or emoji, well, [*here be dragons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons).

Comment: Interesting, I'd love to see an example!

Comment: This does look very interesting, also very complex!

Comment: @PaPaB1nG0 Yes, implementing a `Collator` would be complex, but a good solution if you have many such rules, or if those rules may be changing/expanding. If you can make [the streams-based solution by Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58001397/642706) work for you, do that instead.

Comment: @PaPaB1nG0 Another thought… If your Question is not really about names, and you only showed "Bob" with names as a simplification of your actual business data, then let me suggest the best solution would be looking at the bigger problem. If you have business objects being represented by mere strings whose alphabetical ordering is inconvenient, you should not be relying on such strings. You should be **defining a class to properly represent the business object** and its requisite parts. In that class define a `Comparator`/`Comparable` to properly sort by those parts.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thank you for your consideration I will definitely take note of that for future reference :)